# C# Using Trim() with Split() while "Space" is a Significant Value

Tags: c#, string, list

I'm splitting a string into a list and taking the split parts into another jagged list.

The problem is that my values are separated by spaces and I can't use the `Replace` method on spaces. I just need my `lineList` values to trim without touching the spaces between values.

```
codeText = Regex.Replace(codeText, @"\s+", space.ToString());
lineList = codeText.Split(semicolon).ToList();

foreach(string ln in lineList)
{
    ln.Trim();// Not the right choice on my code.
    blockList = ln.Split(space).ToList();
    parameters.Add(blockList);
}
// First or last member of "parameters" is sometimes "space" 
// and i need to split before loading them in list.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will suffice?

```
foreach(string ln in lineList)
{
      blockList = ln.Trim().Split(space).ToList();
      parameters.Add(blockList);
}
```

Comment: This was a clear solution, solved the problem . I hope when new lines and unpredicted space errors don't affect this. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

Recall that strings are immutable in C#.  The `Trim` method returns a new string which you must assign.  Also, you cannot edit the foreach iteration variable while iterating. Try:

```
foreach(string ln in lineList)
{
    var trimmed = ln.Trim();
    blockList = trimmed.Split(space).ToList();
    parameters.Add(blockList);
}
```

Comment: Solved and I wouldn' know I need to assign the processes in foreach, thanks.